# How to add worker through API?

Tags: development, api

How to add workers through API?

```
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list
```

I don't see any method to add workers or may be it is there but with some other name?

Comment: What are these workers supposed to do?

Comment: Mine like we do in pool.

Comment: There is no miner authentication other than the RPC credentials as specified in the bitcoin.conf file. Just use those credentials to connect to the `bitcoind` daemon.